# ¿Cómo le digo a la macro que me guarde el archivo en .xlsx?

Tags: vba

El código que uso actualmente es el siguiente:

```
RutaArchivo = "C:\Users\bu766pd\Documents\Auditorias\Liberty Fianzas\2017\3ER TRIM 17\Procesos" & "\"
NombreArchivo = "m_" & fianza & "_0917"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=RutaArchivo & NombreArchivo & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes modificar el formato por `FileFormat:=51` y recomendable también modificar la extensión

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=RutaArchivo & NombreArchivo & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
```

O bien usar la etiqueta `xlOpenXMLWorkbook`

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=RutaArchivo & NombreArchivo & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```